# How to keep echo and drop dowm menu on page after submitting

Tags: php, mysqli

In my main application I want the following layout to appear:

1. When application is open, it will display "Course" text input and a submit button to submit course. (This works fine)
2. When user enters in a course and submits, if successful, then it will display the name and id of the course underneath in an echo and underneath the echo it should display a "module" drop down menu and it's submit button to submit module. (This is fine)
3. When user submits a module then the following below should happen:

The echo for the name of the course should remain (At moment this disappears after user submits module

After submitting the module, the module drop down menu should remain     on the page (At moment this disappears

How can I get the above bullet points to be met when submitting module from drop down menu.

```
<?php

     // connect to the database
 include('connect.php');

 /* check connection */
 if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
die();
}

 $courseid = (isset($_POST['courseid'])) ? $_POST['courseid'] : '';

?>

   <h1>DELETING AN ASSESSMENT</h1>

    <form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post">
     <p>Course ID: <input type="text" name="courseid" /><input id="courseSubmit" type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" /></p>      
    </form>


    <?php
  if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $query = "
             SELECT cm.CourseId, cm.ModuleId, 
             c.CourseName,
             m.ModuleName
             FROM Course c
             INNER JOIN Course_Module cm ON c.CourseId = cm.CourseId
             JOIN Module m ON cm.ModuleId = m.ModuleId
             WHERE
             (c.CourseId = ?)
             ORDER BY c.CourseName, m.ModuleId
            ";

$qrystmt=$mysqli->prepare($query);
// You only need to call bind_param once
$qrystmt->bind_param("s",$courseid);
// get result and assign variables (prefix with db)

$qrystmt->execute(); 

$qrystmt->bind_result($dbCourseId,$dbModuleId,$dbCourseName,$dbModuleName);

 $qrystmt->store_result();

$num = $qrystmt->num_rows();

if($num ==0){
    echo "<p>Sorry, No Course was found with this Course ID '$courseid'</p>";
} else { 

    $dataArray = array();

 while ( $qrystmt->fetch() ) { 
      // data array
      $dataArray[$dbCourseId]['CourseName'] = $dbCourseName; 
      $dataArray[$dbCourseId]['Modules'][$dbModuleId]['ModuleName'] = $dbModuleName; 
       // session data
      $_SESSION['idcourse'] = $dbCourseId;
      $_SESSION['namecourse'] = $dbCourseName;

}

 foreach ($dataArray as $courseId => $courseData) {

      $output = ""; 

      $output .= "<p><strong>Course:</strong> " . $courseId .  " - "  . $courseData['CourseName'] . "</p>";

   $moduleHTML = ""; 
   $moduleHTML .= '<select name="modulesDrop" id="modulesDrop">'.PHP_EOL;
   $moduleHTML .= '<option value="">Please Select</option>'.PHP_EOL;      
        foreach ($courseData['Modules'] as $moduleId => $moduleData) {        

        $moduleHTML .= "<option value='$moduleId'>" . $moduleId . " - " .   
    $moduleData['ModuleName'] ."</option>".PHP_EOL;        
  } 
        }
        $moduleHTML .= '</select>';

  echo $output;


    ?>

     <form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post">
     <p>Module: <?php echo $moduleHTML; ?><input id="moduleSubmit" type="submit" value="Submit" name="modulesubmit" /></p>      
    </form> 



    <?php
}
}

 if (isset($_POST['modulesubmit'])) {

 var_dump($_POST['modulesDrop']);

        $sessionquery = "
             SELECT SessionId, SessionDate, SessionTime, ModuleId
             FROM Session
             WHERE
             (ModuleId = ?)
             ORDER BY SessionDate, SessionTime 
            ";

$sessionqrystmt=$mysqli->prepare($sessionquery);
// You only need to call bind_param once
$sessionqrystmt->bind_param("s",$_POST['modulesDrop']);
// get result and assign variables (prefix with db)

$sessionqrystmt->execute(); 

$sessionqrystmt->bind_result($dbSessionId,$dbSessionDate,$dbSessionTime, $dbModuleId);

 $sessionqrystmt->store_result();

$sessionnum = $sessionqrystmt->num_rows();   

    $dataArraySession = array();

 while ( $sessionqrystmt->fetch() ) { 

 $dataArraySession[$dbSessionId]['SessionDate'] = $dbSessionDate; 
 $dataArraySession[$dbSessionId]['SessionTime'] = $dbSessionTime;

}

foreach ($dataArraySession as $sessionId => $sessionData) {



   $sessionHTML = ""; 
   $sessionHTML .= '<select name="session" id="sessionsDrop">'.PHP_EOL;
   $sessionHTML .= '<option value="">Please Select</option>'.PHP_EOL;           
   $sessionHTML .= "<option value='$sessionId'>" . $sessionId . " - " . $sessionData['SessionDate']. " - " . $sessionData['SessionTime'] ."</option>".PHP_EOL;        
   $sessionHTML .= '</select>';

        }


 if ($sessionnum > 0) {

 ?>

     <form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post">
     <p>Sessions: <?php echo $sessionHTML; ?><input id="sessionSubmit" type="submit" value="Submit" name="sesionsubmit" /></p>      
    </form>       

<?php

}

else {
 echo "<p>Sorry, You have No Sessions under this Module</p>";
}


}


    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a couple of issues. The problem you are having is that you are not passing the information "$courseid" from stage 1 to stage 3. To do this simply add the following to stage 2

```
<input type="hidden" name="courseid" value="<?=$courseid?>" />
```

Comment: If I do this then if I search for a legitimate courseid, it is then not able to find the courseid, can you show me where I am suppose to put this line of code please above?

Comment: Between the form tags in the `if (isset($_POST['submit']))` enclosure. The problems is that you need to be able to maintain state. There are several ways to do this. One way like I suggested above is to make sure that any information you need in stage 3 is passed from stage 1 and stage 2. This is usually done by using the input type hidden tag. Another (and probably easier) is to use sessions, here is a link to a sample case http://goo.gl/dwVb6 (in your case you are posting to the same page). Get detailed information about sessions here http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php